# Is it possible to create a limited number of threads to send a webRequest?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
Friend Function SendToServer(ByVal Datos As List(Of String), ByVal User As String, ByVal Password As String) As String

    Dim ErrorCount As Integer = 0

    BGW_Report("Sending " & Datos.Count.ToString & " event(s).", Color.Purple)

    Try
        For Each Eventox As String In Datos
            Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Eventox)

            Dim xUri As New Uri(My.Settings.WebAddress)
            Dim result_post = SendRequest(xUri, data, "application/json", "POST")

            If Not result_post.Contains("Process OK") Then
                ErrorCount += 1
            End If
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

        BGW_Report("ErrorCount: " & ErrorCount, Color.Red)
        BGW_Report(ex.Message, Color.Red)
        BGW_Report(ex.StackTrace, Color.OrangeRed)

        ErrorCount = -1
    End Try

    Return ErrorCount

End Function

Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
    Dim response As String
    Dim request As WebRequest

    request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
    request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
    request.ContentType = contentType
    request.Method = method
   
    Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream
        requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
        requestStream.Close()

        Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
            Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
                response = reader.ReadToEnd()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using

    Return response
End Function
```

This web request is taking around half a second to answer and I have several reports to send, so I was thinking about creating several threads, but limited to 20 at most, inside the `For Each` routine.

How I can do this?

I'm new to multithreading; I never used more than two `BackgroundWorkers`.

I'm using a BackgroundWorker to call the function SendToServer.

Net Framework 4.0 VS2022

Comment: What is `SendRequest`?

Comment: What HTTP client are you using? `WebClient`? `HttpWebRequest`? `HttpClient`? What version of .NET are you using? Are you using `IHttpClientFactory`? Is there a reason you're not using the async API?

Comment: @Dai I've added some code and more info as you requested. I don't know what API are you talking about, I always use my own code, never external API/code.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, there is an easier solution but this should work.

Import threading

```
Imports System.Threading
```

Create a Class to store the parameters

```
Public class ThreadParams
    Public uri As Uri
    Public jsonDataBytes As Byte()
    Public contentType As String
    Public method As String
End Class
```

Create the Sub for the Thread. It must have one Object type parameter

```
Public Sub ThreadSub(params As Object)
    Dim myThreadParams As ThreadParams=params
    SendRequest(myThreadParams.uri, myThreadParams.jsonDataBytes , myThreadParams.contentType , myThreadParams.method )
End Sub
```

Create the loop to create the threads

```
Public Sub startThreads()
    For i=0 To 20

        Dim threadParams As New ThreadParams
        threadParams.uri=...
        threadParams.jsonDataBytes=...
        threadParams.contentType=...
        threadParams.method=...

        Dim thr As New Thread(AddressOf ThreadSub)
        thr.Start(threadParams)
    Next
End Sub
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is possible to get the result of each Thread?

Comment: You can process the result of the SendRequest function inside ThreadSub, but it will be executed on that thread, so if you want to make changes on the UI thread then use Invoke inside the ThreadSub. E.g. MyForm.Invoke(Sub()  ...do ui changes... End Sub)

Comment: I need to count the success/error results. A global variable could be accessed from the Thread? Maybe I can set to zero both variables and each finished Thread will increase those variables depending on the result, if end ok increase the Success variable or the Error variable if get an error as answer.

Comment: A variable is accessible inside the thread if it's accessible in the ThreadSub.  However the parallel modification of the same variable could cause unpredicted results. You should do that inside the Invoke. Eg. MyForm.Invoke(Sub() ErrorCount+=1 End Sub) . The problem is that you won't know when you should check the ErrorCount variable for the final result. By the way, why not just create a sub to create a Background Worker and call it in a for loop?